# Printing variable to console showing unexpected behavior

Tags: java, console, variable-assignment

The following piece of code was an attempt to print the largest sum out of all the subarrays of the given ArrayList C, provided that the sum is not greater than the value given to a variable, B.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> C=new ArrayList <> ();
        Collections.addAll(C,7,1,8,5,8,5,3,3,5);
        int B=999;
        int maxSum=0;
        // int TheRealMax=0;
        for(int i=0;i<C.size();i++){
            for(int j=i;j<C.size();j++){
                
                for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){
                    
                        maxSum+=C.get(k);
                        if(maxSum>B)
                            maxSum-=C.get(k);
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxSum);
    }
}
```

Now I know that the code is wrong and not working correctly and I don't need the correct code. 
What I am really perplexed by is the value (that of maxSum) that is being printed to the console. I have observed the following: for "small values" of B,  take 99, the value being printed (of maxSum) is the value of B itself. And for "larger values" of B, say, 999 and even something like 9784535, etc, etc, you get the idea, the value that is displayed is "843". 
It  is strange that maxSum somehow appears to acquire the value of B even though there isn't any linkage between either variable in the code except for a condition check. And I am at a loss as to where exactly the number 843 comes from either. 
**All I want to know is, from where does maxSum get these values?**

Comment: I think you're just iterating through C enough that your sum is hitting the limit you put in the code. When you get the code working, it should do what you expect.

Comment: ok, I think that explains it... the sum is hitting the variable and therefore shows B's value for relatively smaller values (Edit: [but]) for "large" values, there still is this weird behavior which shows 843 in the console. Anyway, I'll take that explanation for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found few issues with your code -

1. You're not resetting `maxSum` after each subarray iteration
2. Time Complexity - `O(n^3)`

**Fix**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> C=new ArrayList <> ();
        Collections.addAll(C,7,1,8,5,8,5,3,3,5);
        int B=999;
        int maxSum=0;
        // int TheRealMax=0;
        for(int i=0;i<C.size();i++){
            for(int j=i;j<C.size();j++){
                int subArraySum = 0; //This will hold the Sum of each subarray
                for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){
                        subArraySum+=C.get(k);
                        if(subArraySum>B){
                            subArraySum-=C.get(k);
                            break; //If sum exeeds the B break the loop
                        }
                    
                }
                if(subArraySum>maxSum)
                    maxSum=subArraySum;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxSum);
    }
}
```

**But this piece of code has time complexity of `O(n^3)` which can cause issue if input size is large, I highly recommend using Kadane's algorithm as it'll reduce your time complexity to `O(n)` and space complexity to `O(1)`**

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer but my query was, why is the behavior of maxSum variable in a strange way? I'm aware that the code is incorrect but I also know that for such a simple code, the behavior of the maxSum variable is rather confusing.. any help in assisting to see how and why it is, would be much appreciated.